# Google Co-laboratory notebook PDF download

Tags: pdf-generation, google-colaboratory

Google Co-laboratory notebook doesn't have the "Download as" dropdown menu item in "File" menu like standalone Jupyter does. How to download the notebook as PDF?

Comment: using ctrl+p in the browser, go to options and click "Background graphics". The saved pdf will be of much higher quality and will have better formatting.

Comment: Beware, on firefox, parts of the page are cropped (top and bottom).

Answer (score 45):

You can also run the solution of mayurmadnani directly on Colab.
Therefore create a new Python workbook in Colab and connect it to a runtime.
Install the necessary packages into the virtual machine with:

```
!apt-get install texlive texlive-xetex texlive-latex-extra pandoc
!pip install pypandoc
```

Mount your google drive to get access to your ipynb files

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/drive')
```

I had to copy the files from the drive to the working directory,
because the drive is/was mounted as read only.

```
!cp drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Untitled.ipynb ./
```

Then you can run the converter.

```
!jupyter nbconvert --to PDF "Untitled.ipynb"
```

Then you can download the file in the left side panel.

Comment: Cool, that works. Although a little overkill for the job, it gives much insight into how to work with colab and drive. Thanks.

Comment: Having trouble with install texlive-xetex on Google Colab. Getting an error - Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 libgs9-common all 9.26~dfsg+0-0ubuntu0.18.04.10
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.174 80]...and similar lines to this effect. Worked seamlessly on my local machine though.

Comment: Just a little fix. Intead `!cp drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Untitled.ipynb ./` use `!cp "./drive/My Drive/Colab Notebooks/Untitled.ipynb" ./` because the blank spaces

Comment: or ```!cp /content/drive/My\ Drive/Colab\ Notebooks/yourfile.ipynb ./```

Comment: the problem with this method is it wont store the output 
It'd just store the code cells

Answer (score 15):

Use the built-in browser print. Then, save the result as a pdf.

Comment: interesting solution, but no Table of Contents

Comment: It works for most notebooks, but not works well for those notebooks with embed javascript content.

Answer (score 13):

@user10914779's answer worked for me. But if you are looking for a shorter and readable code then you can take a look at this Github repo: [colab-pdf](https://github.com/brpy/colab-pdf).

You can paste the following code in the last cell of your colab notebook and run it. It will generate a PDF file and save it to your drive.

```
!wget -nc https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brpy/colab-pdf/master/colab_pdf.py
from colab_pdf import colab_pdf
colab_pdf('name-of-the-notebook.ipynb')
```

You can provide the name of the notebook to colab_pdf('name-of-the-notebook.ipynb'). If you are not interested in the output that this codeblock produces then you can hide it using '%%capture'

```
%%capture
!wget -nc https://raw.githubusercontent.com/brpy/colab-pdf/master/colab_pdf.py
from colab_pdf import colab_pdf
```

Comment: Fantastic @Osmani. Upvoted!

Comment: @DeepakTatyajiAhire, thanks! Glad to help :)

Comment: Hello, where does it exactly save?

Comment: From the documentation of the library, "This requires that you have already mounted your google drive in your notebook. If not, this will attempt to Mount your drive, which may ask for your authentication."

Answer (score 9):

Try any one:

1. You have an option File > Download .ipynb. Use below command to convert ipynb to pdf or any other format

> jupyter nbconvert --to FORMAT notebook.ipynb

See usage guide: https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

2. As mentoned by Bob, use print option to save as pdf. Here, you may lose text if it goes out of the page

Comment: That makes sense only if one already have a local jupyter installed. I tried it on my machine and got "nbconvert.utils.pandoc.PandocMissing: Pandoc wasn't found." error. I think if I would just open the notebook on my machine and use "Download as" to save to pdf. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

1. Download .ipynb file
2. Download as html
3. Print PDF from browser

Answer (score 4):

check here for video: https://youtu.be/n2Cd9NCZtZk

```
  %cd go_to_your_path

#run these.

!sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-generic-recommended

!jupyter nbconvert --to pdf fileName.ipynb
```

Answer (score 0):

so to browser print option and select cancel option in that you will get save as pdf.

Answer (score 0):

1. download the .ipynb file from colab from file->download .ipynb
2. Then upload it to your jupyter notebook and download it in pdf format as you used to in stand-alone jupyter.

Since .ipynb files take a few MBs of data at maximum.

Answer (score 0):

If (You are using jupyter the easier way I found was to)

- Download the file in latex.
- Upload it to overleaf.
- And then download it as a pdf

Else if ( You are using google collab)

- Download as ipynb
- Upload to jupyter and repeat the above steps.

Answer (score 0):

You first download the related packages for it with the following code:

```
!sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-plain-generic
```

Then run the code below to convert the corresponding named IPYNB file to convert to the same name PDF file.

```
!jupyter nbconvert --to pdf /content/Text_Summarization.ipynb
```

A Note:
If you have any blanks on the file name, you should add a backslash to the code just like below:

```
!jupyter nbconvert --to pdf /content/Text\ Preprocessing\ and\ BoW.ipynb
```

Answer (score 0):

For macOS users, I found exporting to PDF with nbconvert following these steps worked well.
Run the below commands in your terminal. If using Anaconda, ensure to run them in the base environment.

1. pip install nbconvert[webpdf]
2. jupyter nbconvert --to webpdf --allow-chromium-download path/name_to_notebook_file.ipynb
   PS: The --allow-chromium-download flag should be added once to install Chromium.

If you want to exclude code in the PDF export, run jupyter nbconvert --to webpdf --no-input path/name_to_notebook-file.ipynb

Ref: https://mljar.com/blog/jupyter-notebook-pdf/

Answer (score 0):

For me the easiest way in collab:

`***ctrl+P***` (Print) and there, instead of printing the page, just click Microsoft Print to PDF. You will have your notebook in PDF in your downloads.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1: Exporting to HTML then to PDF format
!jupyter nbconvert --to html /content/KNN.ipynb

Method 2: Exporting directly to PDF format
!sudo apt-get install texlive-xetex texlive-fonts-recommended texlive-plain-generic
!jupyter nbconvert --to pdf /content/KNN.ipynb

Ref: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-Ti9Mm21uVc&t=309s&ab_channel=AdrianDolinay

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve how it looks on colab, and if you don't mind things getting flattened, you could use the chrome extension -- `GoFullPage - Full Page Screen Capture`

https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/gofullpage-full-page-scre/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl?pli=1

Answer (score -1):

If you are using colab -

1. go to file then click on print,
2. there will be a "destination" tab,
3. choose the "save as pdf" option over there

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should [vote it up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)